# The website cannot display the page issue

Tags: asp-classic

I am stuck in vary basic problem "The website cannot display the page "

The page "sfcRecInsplst.asp" page is there if i changed it to  szhref="http://google.com/" it redirecting to the google. but why not  sfcRecInsplst.asp page?

What should i check? how to solve this issue

```
    function DoSearch(){
    var szhref;
    var szplantid;
    var szwono;
    var szskuno;
    var szcartonpn;
    var szfromdate;
    var sztodate;


    szfromdate=document.search.lfromdate.value;
    sztodate=document.search.ltodate.value;
    szplantid=document.search.lPlantid.value;
    szhref="sfcRecInsplst.asp?pfromdate=" + szfromdate +"&ptodate=" + sztodate+"&lplantid=" + szplantid;
    win=window.open(szhref,'CartonUsagerpt','toolbar=yes,top=0,left=0,width=<%=session("width")%>,height=<%=session("height")-100%>,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,maximize=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes,statusbar=yes'); 
    win.focus;
        }

function DoSearchReset() {
        document.search.reset();
     }

function lRecestatus_onkeypress(){
    if (window.event.keyCode ==13) 
    {
        DoSearch();
    }
}

</script>

<table width="80%" bgcolor="#c0c0c0" border="1" rules="NONE" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td  align=right valign=bottom>
            <a href="JavaScript:DoSearch();">
            <img src="/images/goe.gif" border="0" alt="Search" valign="middle"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1">Go</font></a>
            <a href="JavaScript:DoSearchReset();">
            <img src="/images/resete.gif" border="0" alt="Reset" valign="middle"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1">Reset</font></a>
```

Comment: Check the IIS logs for the requests for ""sfcRecInsplst.asp". Check to see if an error is being logged.

Comment: Is your server configured to display friendly asp error messages.  See this - http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp

Comment: it showing me error as " /SFC/sfcRecInsplst.asp pfromdate=2016-01-11&ptodate=2016-01-11&lplantid=ALL|14|ASP_0131|Disallowed_Parent_Path 80 - 10.18.143.107 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/5.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET+CLR+1.1.4322;+.NET4.0E;+InfoPath.2) 500 0 0"    What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what version of IIS you are using, but in IIS 8 you can enable parent paths by doing the following:

1. Under Sites, click on your web site.
2. In the Features View pane, double-click on ASP.
3. Set Enable Parent Paths to True.

You may need to restart IIS for it to take effect.